# Updating column values at runtime using Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have a set of 137 text files and each file has data in the format name, sex, number of births. Each file has the year name appended to its name, e.g. 'yob1881.txt'

I want to data from these 137 files and append them into a dataframe and in the process add a new column for year.

This is what I've done so far:

```
filenames = glob('yob*.txt')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in filenames:
  startPOS = df.shape[0]
  df = df.append(pd.read_csv(x, header=None))
  endPOS = df.shape[0]
  df.loc[startPOS:endPOS+1, 'year'] = int(x.split('.')[0][-4:])
```

But, the code throws error in the last line. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are planning to add the error message and traceback to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a quick thing which I can see in your code. Once you fetch the data from your first file you are appending that to **df** and also adding a year variable at the end.

But when you will do the same for second time **df** already contains variable "year". That is a mismatch in number of variables present in **df**. One quick fix could be.

```
filenames = glob('yob*.txt')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in filenames:
    df_new = pd.read_csv(x, header=None)
    df_new["year"] = int(x.split('.')[0][-4:])
    df = df.append(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tanmoy's reply that the error log would be nice to see.
That said, assuming, as you say that the content of each file has the same columns, it would be easier to add the date to each file's DataFrame first and then concatenate all of them:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

data = []

filenames = glob('yob*.txt')
for x in filenames:
  year = int(re.search("(\d+)", x).group())
  data.append(pd.read_csv(x, header=None))
  data[-1]['year'] = [year, ] * data[-1].shape[0]

df = pd.concat(data)
```

Something like this should do the trick for what you are asking.